# FLUTTER :: after updating the data, the data cannot be saved to the database

Tags: flutter

I'm a new flutter user, this time I want to make an update data using **SharedPreferences**, but when I try to run the application there is no error and I try to update the data, when I click update the data is not saved to the database it is only saved meanwhile, when I refresh the updated database it doesn't change. Can a friend help me with my source code snippet below

```
void _update() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    Map<String, String> data = {
      "body1" : _nama_debiturController.text,
      "body2" : _alamatController.text,
      "body3" : _no_telpController.text,
      "body4" : _no_ktpController.text,
      "body5" : _no_selularController.text
    };
    print(data);

    var res = await Network().updateData(NasabahService.baseUrl, 'mstdebitur' , data);
    var body = json.decode(res.body);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      localStorage.setString('mstdebitur', json.encode(body['mstdebitur']));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('Berhasil Disimpan'),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      ));

    } else {
      if (body['message']['nama_debitur'] != null) {
        _showMsg(body['message']['nama_debitur'][0].toString());
      } else if (body['message']['alamat'] != null) {
        _showMsg(body['message']['alamat'][0].toString());
      } else if (body['message']['no_telp'] != null) {
        _showMsg(body['message']['no_telp'][0].toString());
      }
      else if (body['message']['no_ktp'] != null) {
        _showMsg(body['message']['no_ktp'][0].toString());
      }
      else if (body['message']['no_selular'] != null) {
        _showMsg(body['message']['no_selular'][0].toString());
      }
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: Text("Gagal")));
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't save object as string in shared preferences that's why you are not retrieving any data. Solution is to use a database to store it.

You can search Flutter databases and will get many options such as sqlite, realm, objectBox etc. They will have the documentation for how to use them.

And for the notification/knowing in your code that some data has been updated inside database, there are such features in realm you can check its documentation, where you will have streams which update as some data is updated inside the database.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can't, it's still not saved with the full source code. can you solve this problem? I also hope that when I enter the update form, it will be filled in according to the index https://github.com/azmi1700018002/akm-front

Comment: try to save the data without encoding it....

Comment: ok I got it after looking at your repo and doing some Rnd, actually you are trying to save an object inside a string and that's why its not working. I would suggest trying a database solution like sqlite, objectBox, realm etc. You can just search flutter database and you will get plenty of options along with how to implement them.

Comment: Then about whether you can provide modifications to my source code so that updates can be stored in the database ? Please help me